# Append N >= 1 elements to a list

Tags: python, list, append, extend

I am building a list in python by looping through some JSON blobs and appending elements.  Sometimes the elements are single, sometimes double (or more).

```
my_list = []    
for j in jsons:
  my_list.append(j['foo'])
```

`my_list` ends up being `['a1', 'b1', ['c1', 'c2']]`

If I use extend instead I get `['a', '1', 'b', '1', 'c1', 'c2']`.

Do I have to first check if what I'm appending is a list, and then append it element-wise?  Or is there a better function that already does this?

Comment: explicitly checking seems reasonable enough, given the unreasonable irregularity of your JSON blobs. But I would check if it is a list, then `.extend`, otherwise, `.append`. Another approach is to just flatten later... but probably best just to check.

Comment: Why isn't the data organized consistently to begin with? Maybe you can fix the code that creates it.

Comment: Would that I could @Barmar  , but it's public data provided by a government.

Comment: This might work too `[items for i in jsons for items in (i['foo'] if isinstance(i['foo'],list) else [i['foo']])]`

Comment: @AsheKetchum yes, that would work, but that is *exactly what he said by checking....*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ok? I'm sorry I don't quite get your point. I thought it was straightforward that we needed to check, so I provided a way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to explicitly check each item type.

For instance, you can write:

```
# sample jsons
jsons = [{'foo': 'a1'},
         {'foo': 'b1'},
         {'foo': ['c1', 'c2']}]

my_list = []
for json in jsons:
    item = json['foo']
    if isinstance(item, list):
        my_list.extend(item)
    else:
        my_list.append(item)
```

You get:

```
['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'c2']
```

But, with Python you can use a [ternary conditional expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/394809/1513933) to simplify:

```
my_list = []
for json in jsons:
    item = json['foo']
    my_list.extend(item if isinstance(item, list) else [item])
```

Comment: You can also use the ternary expression to select the correct method to call, which avoids creating the temporary list to wrap `item`. `(mylist.extend if isinstance(item, list) else mylist.append)(item)`.

Comment: You right, it's unusual and can be considered an advanced usage… ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `singledispatch` decorator to move some of the boilerplate out of your main loop. The decorator is available from the `functools` module in the standard library starting in Python 3.4, or via the `singledispatch` module on PyPi.

This defines a function `adder` which behaves differently depending on the type of its (first) argument.

```
@singledispatch
def adder(item):
    mylist.append(item)

@adder.register(list)
def _(item):
    mylist.extend(item)

mylist = []
for json in jsons:
    adder(json['foo'])
```